# Is there such a thing as a voltage level that is safe for humans in all circumstances?

Tags: safety

My question is naive but I'm having a hard time finding a precise yes/no answer when I ask google. The general advice seems to be "it depends", but are there voltage levels where it really does not depend? My intuition is that there are some voltages (eg. 5v) that are so low that it does not matter how many amps the power source can supply because the human body will give enough resistance, even in worst case scenarios, so that current will be limited to safe levels. Is this intuition correct or am I looking at this the wrong way?

Comment: Which body part? Your finger can withstand a lot more voltage than your heart.

Comment: Also, how far apart in distance do you assume the voltage difference to be?  Resistance decreases with as the distance decreases.

Comment: This would seem to be a question about human [biology.se] rather than about engineering

Comment: @EnergyNumbers - Biomedical engineers need to be concerned with this subject.  That said, this question is currently too broad to be reasonably answered in the SE Q&A format.

Answer (score 1):

If there is a universally safe voltage level, it is so low to be of little practical value, probably in the 10s of mV range.

The problem with your spec is that it's current that causes the problems, not voltage.  Given a particular voltage, the current depends on the resistance, which can vary greatly between different points of the body.

Inside, we are largely bags of saltwater, which has low resistivity.  Our skin, in contrast, has high resistance, although that varies greatly depending on wetness.

For most "ordinary" cases, 5 V is so low compared to our skin resistance that you can't even feel it.  However, if I dipped two fingers in salt water and then touched them across a 5 V supply, I probably would feel it.  Take a 9 V battery and touch it briefly to your tongue.  You will definitely feel that, and it will be rather unpleasant.  If you're clever, you can kill yourself with a 12 V car battery.

So far, that's all been outside the body.  If you connect directly to points inside the body, then not only will the current for the same voltage be much higher, but depending on where you connect, the current tolerance can be much lower.  I expect 100 µA thru the heart muscle in the right place could cause serious problems.  I don't know how much voltage that would take, but probably much less than 5 V.  Even a few 100 mV between selected points in the brain can very likely mess up critical systems.

Comment: From memories of courses years ago, your guess is fairly accurate regarding how trivial the amount of power is required in order to disrupt things like the heart.  I want to say that the current needed to be on the order of mA, but the voltage could be lower than 100 mV.  Determining if externally applied electricity would be harmful runs into a devil's triangle of current, voltage, and frequency.